# Stack react-bootstrap accordian as horizontal

Tags: react-bootstrap

We have requirement where we have some category group which needs to be rendered as accordian and it should look like following;

[image]

On expansion, it needs to expand itself and show body. We created separate component which will accept array of string and few helper functions but all of this accordian rendered as vertical on parent component

```js
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import { generateUniqueComponentKey } from "../../utils/Helper";


const RenderButtonGroup = ({btnGroups, handleFilterGroupClick, selectedFilterGroup}) => {
    console.log('selectedFilterGroup ', selectedFilterGroup)
    const renderBtgGroup = () => {
        if (btnGroups){
            let btnItems = btnGroups && btnGroups.map(item => {
                let myKey = generateUniqueComponentKey();
                return (
                    <>
                        <ListGroupItem 
                            eventKey={myKey}
                            key={myKey}
                            variant="warning"
                            onClick={handleFilterGroupClick}
                            active={selectedFilterGroup[0] === item ? true : false}
                        >{item}</ListGroupItem>
                    </>
                )

            })

            return(
                <ListGroup>{btnItems}</ListGroup>
            )
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="d-flex">
            {renderBtgGroup()}
        </div>
    )
}

export default RenderButtonGroup;
```

Not CSS expert so don't know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the Grid component with 3 columns: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/